# How to disable microphone auto increase in volume?

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone

My friend on Skype constantly has his microphone volume increased automatically. After he says something in a loud voice the microphone goes back to normal. This also happens on RaidCall.

It seems this problem is activated when he says something "whispering".

Using different headsets did not solve the problem, so we believe this is some software related problem.

Any idea what is causing it?

```
Notebook: samsung rv 411
OS      : Win7
```

Comment: Have you tried messing around with the mic settings in the Control Panel under Sound>Recording.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's causing it is that the option to allow programs control over the device is set as active. To disable this there are two steps. A windows step and a Skype step. You will also want to check any others (like teamspeak and the like) that also have auto adjust options.

On the Windows side:

- Goto ***Control panel***
- Open ***Sound***
- Click on ***Recording*** tab[image: recording tab]
- select your mic and click the ***properties*** button on the bottom.
  [image: sound2]
- Uncheck the ***Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device***

The Skype step:

- Click ***Tools*** at the top of Skype window
- Select ***Options***
- On the left side of the Skype screen select ***Audio settings***
- Under Microphone, uncheck ***Automaticly adjust Microphone settings***

[image: Skype1]

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Manage Audio Devices

On the communications tab try selecting "Do nothing".

Comment: His microphone volume changes, not other computer sounds. In a conference other members doesn't have this problem, but we all can hear this guy microphone really loud. Doing that will fix this? Is that a bug then?

Answer (score -1):

Check `Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device` in sound options that you went by control panel and disable skype one, after that reduce the microphone volume in the options of application you use.